# ODBC Connection to ORACLE in R

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I am using both the DBI and ODBC package in "R" in order to make a connection to an ORACLE database.

Here is the connection code I am using:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "ORACLE",
                      Host   = "orasada.ca",
                      SVC    = "STG",
                      UID    = "username",
                      PWD    = "password",
                      Port   =  1521)
```

Everything looks fine to me, but I keep getting this error:

**Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

Any ideas on what I can change to make a successful connection?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the oracle by using SQL developer or could you do a TNS ping and chek?

Comment: It is typically sensitive to case of the argument names. Try `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver="...", server="orasada.ca", uid="username", pwd="password", port=1521)`. Because different drivers mandate different parameters (and none of that is something that the `odbc` package can currently tell you), you may need to search around for the right combination. For instance, I've seen `uid=` on one DBMS and `user=` on another.

Comment: Is your Oracle client installed and configured? ODBC is an interface layer on top of Oracle Client; it does not replace Oracle Client. The driver specification should reflect that.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Yes I am able to connect to the ORACLE via SQL developer, just not make the connection via "R".

Comment: @pmdba That might be the issue. I have made a request to our corporate team to have ORACLE Client installed on my machine to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @pmdba I had the ORACLE client version 11.2 installed as well as ORACLE ODBC however I am still getting the same error unfortunately.

Is there a more specific driver string I should use instead of just ORACLE?

Comment: You have to specify a more precise client, like .connection_string = "Driver={**Oracle dans OraClient10g_home1**};DBQ=host:port/db_name;..." if you're on windows, see https://guillaumepressiat.github.io/blog/2019/11/oraclyr for instance

Comment: were you able to connect following doc in link above? If yes please say it. It seems to be almost ok reading your new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179802/convert-oracle-table-to-dataframe-in-r ; thanks